# Visual Studio 2015 closes Python console too soon

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I test a Python script in VS 2015, I can see some kind of error message flash on the console, then the console closes before I can look at it.

I've tried running it both with debugging (F5) and without (Ctrl-F5).

Putting some kind of delay in the last line of script doesn't appear to change things (unsurprising, since I'm sure the script doesn't execute that far.)

I've looked here [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio)

Some answers suggest changing a setting here:

```
Properties>Configuration Properties> Linker> System > 
select Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) in SubSystem option.
```

...but my version of VS (Community 2015) doesn't have that same feature (at least, not that I can find).  When I right-click and select Properties for this project, I get this:

[image: screenshot]

This answer: [Python file closes instantly in MS visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967302/python-file-closes-instantly-in-ms-visual-studio-2015)

...looked promising, but I already have looked at that setting:

[image: Python Tools screenshot]

Comment: maybe it doesn't work when the python file has a syntax error. Can you post it here?

Comment: The error is "AttributeError: 'str' objcet has no attribute 'read'."  That's a simple error I can fix.  But in order to find out what it was that flashed in the console, I had to **video-screen-capture the output at 60 fps then rewind the video to see** like a theatrical "zoom in and enhance" sequence!  It'd be easier if the console just "stuck."  On another computer running VS 2015, it doesn't do this.  It's gotta be a weird setting somewhere.

Comment: okay, you're probably right. Another way of workarounding this would be to run your .py file in a CMD console. Much easier than capturing the screen.